# Why are unipotent elements of a linear Lie/algebraic group well defined?

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

For a Lie group $G$ embedded in some $SL_n$, unipotent elements are defined to be those which satisfy $(x-I)^n = 0$ for some large enough $n$. However, this definition seems to depend on the manner in which $G$ is embedded inside $SL_n$. Is it true that for any two embeddings of $G$ in $SL_n$ and $SL_m$, the unipotent elements from the first representation are the same as the ones from the second representation? If not, can we strengthen assumptions on $G$ to make this happen, like require $G$ to be semisimple? What about when we additionally require $G$ to algebraic, and the corresponding embeddings to be algebraic as well?

Comment: Why do think this depends on the embedding? If $f$ is the embedding, then you must have $f((x - I)^n) = (f(x) - 1)^n$ and as $f$ is an embedding, and hence $1$-$1$, $x$ will be unipotent iff $f(x)$ is.

Comment: Since $f$ is an embedding, it's just an injective group homomorphism from $G$ to some $SL_n$, and it will certainly preserve powers, i.e. $f(x^n) = f(x)^n$, but it's not clear that it will preserve sums, i.e. $f(x-I) = f(x) - I$.

Comment: You are quite right: I misread the question and thought you were talking about embeddings of algebras.

Comment: Jantzen defines an algebraic group to be unipotent if the trivial representation is the only simple representation. Equivalently, every nonzero representation has nonzero fixed points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this off the unanswered list.

If we're talking about algebraic groups, which you seem to indicate is at least one of your interests then yes, this is true. Note that unipotence in $\text{SL}_n$ is the same as that in $\text{GL}_n$. Thus, one can apply [Mil, Theorem 9.18].

[Mil] Milne, J.S., 2017. Algebraic groups: The theory of group schemes of finite type over a field (Vol. 170). Cambridge University Press.